# Ecore_Job memory leak possibility?

Tags: c, tizen

I need simple threading capabilities on an interval basis with `Ecore_Job`. I am creating `Ecore_Job` and calling it and I am not deleting it and not shutting down with `ecore_shutdown();`

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
char *str = "Hello world";

Ecore_Job *job;

job = ecore_job_add(printHelloWorld_cb, str); //this printHelloWorld_cb just prints the msg.

(void)job;
```

Now this part of code is running on another `ecore_timer_add()` function to run it properly periodically. This is the reason behind not using `ecore_shutdown();`.

Now will this cause memory leak? If so how can I make it efficient with minimal code? if that `Ecore_Job *job` is not remove automatically, how many jobs can be created this way?

Please answer if you know about it.

Answer (score 0):

ecore_job is freed automatically after it is processed. ecore_job registers _ecore_job_event_free callback when it is added.

```
EAPI Ecore_Job *ecore_job_add(Ecore_Cb func, const void *data) {
   ...
   job = calloc(1, sizeof (Ecore_Job));                                                    
   if (!job) return NULL;
   job->event = ecore_event_add(ecore_event_job_type, job, _ecore_job_event_free, job);
   ...
}

static void
_ecore_job_event_free(void *data,             
                  void *job EINA_UNUSED){
   free(data); //data is job
}
```

So I recommend you use valgrind to find memory leak.